# MySQL query returns not what I expected because of spaces in database record and I'm not sure what to about it

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've created a hyperlink that leads to a page that lists all the tags I have in my database like this :

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT tag FROM tags";
echo "<ul id='ulTags'>";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo '<a href="specificTag.php?='.$row['tag'].'"><li class="listTags">'.$row['tag'].'</li></a>';
}
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

As you can see, once you click a certain tag, you're send to another page that takes the URL and based on it checks which tag you clicked on the previous page like this :

```
<?php

    $tagName = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    $realTagName = substr($tagName, 1);

    echo $realTagName;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag='$realTagName'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $getResult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $tagId = $getResult['id'];

    echo $tagId;

    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM tagsconnection WHERE tagid='$tagId'";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
    $getResult2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
    $imageId = $getResult2['imageid'];

    echo $imageId;

?>
```

Now the problem I face is that if one of the tags in the database has spaces, the spaces are replaced with %20 in the URL, which messes with my queries because the $realTagName will not be the same as the tag in the database.
For example, a tag called Blue will work just fine in the query but a tag called Blue Whale will not work because my $realTagName is gonna be Blue%20Whale. Any ideas how to get past this problem?

Comment: Have you heard of [`urldecode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)? Or you could directly work with `$_GET`.

Comment: No but after taking a look, it seems like the perfect fix. Thanks a lot!

Comment: As a side node: You should validate the parameters and read up on prepared statements.